# all citations are missing in latexdiff

Tags: citing, latexdiff

I have used `latexdiff` to generate a newDiff.tex and then compiled it with the normall `pdflatex`-`bibtex` and then twice `pdflatex`, but I received many warnings for the each citations and the output pdf is missing all citations (all is [?] right now.) Can anyone address me about it? On all new.tex and old.tex files, I am using the same .bib file.

example of the warning:

```
[![LaTeX Warning: Citation `ashouri2014bayesian' on page 16 undefined on input lin
e 1029.][1]][1]
```

This is a sample output:

[image]

it has even generated the .bbl file and yet can't output it in the pdf:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ashouri, Mariani, Palermo, and
  Silvano}{Ashouri et~al\mbox{.}}{2014}]%
        {ashouri2014bayesian}
{Amir~Hossein Ashouri}, {Giovanni Mariani}, {Gianluca Palermo}, {and} {Cristina
  Silvano}. 2014.
\newblock \showarticletitle{A Bayesian network approach for compiler
  auto-tuning for embedded processors}. In {\em Embedded Systems for Real-time
  Multimedia (ESTIMedia), 2014 IEEE 12th Symposium on}. IEEE, 90--97.
\newblock
```

Comment: Do your paths still match?

Comment: if you mean the path to .bib file, yes. all files are in the same directory

Comment: then I am out of ideas.

Comment: Without a fuller example (old file, new file, diff file), reduced to an MWE, it is hard to know what the problem is. I have certainly run the case you describe successfully. At the very least post how your \bibliography command apppears in the diff.tex file. In any case I recommend using --flatten option with bibliographies, because then you also get markup of the bibliography. For this you have to generate both old.bbl and new.bbl (or whatever your new and old files are called)

Comment: This is how i did the workaround, i put the `.bbl` generated of the new.tex at the end of the difflatex.tex and commented the line redering to the .bib file. At least i have a correct output this way

Comment: That seems labour-intensive if you ever have to rerun comparison. --flatten basically does the same thing automatically

Comment: This works correctly on standard files. Please provide a concrete example demonstrating the problem.